# Backbone.js model validation, no clue what is wrong here?

Tags: javascript, validation, backbone.js

I have no idea why the errors are not popping up or prohibiting from something like this to occur. I am trying to figure out how to validate on this backbone model. Using it for client-side and learning with it.

This is currently setting a string with nothing in it.

```
var user = new User();
user.set({'firstName': ''}, {validate:true});
```

my backbone code

```
var User = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        firstName: 'J.R.',
        lastName: 'Smith',
        email: 'jsmith@knicks.com',
        phone: '212-424-6234',
        birthday: '03/05/1982',
        city: 'New York'

    },

    validate: function(attrs) {
        if(!attrs.firstName) {
            return 'You must enter a real name.'
        },
        if(!attrs.lastName) {
            return 'You must enter a real name.'
        },
        if(attrs.email.length < 5 ) {
            return 'You must enter a real email.'
        },
        if(attrs.phone.length < 10 && attrs.phone === int) {
            return 'You must enter a real phone number, if you did please remove the dash and spaces.'
        },
        if(attrs.city.length < 2 ) {
            return 'You must enter a real city.'
        },
    },

    location: function(){
        return this.get('firstName') + ' ' + this.get('lastName') + 'is currently in ' + this.get('city') + '.';
    },

    initialize: function() {



        this.on('invalid', function(model, invalid){
            console.log(invalid);
            //when setting a user user.set('age', -55, {validate : true}); the validate true makes sure it validates
        });
    },

});
```

Comment: Out of interest, is the model.validationError property being set to anything?  Also, is the 'invalid' handler being reached at all?

Comment: The invalid error is not being reached, and the property is not being set to anything.

Comment: Works fine (http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/ekH4D/) if you remove all the stray commas in your `validate` method.

Comment: I removed it, still does not error or prevent me from changing it, in the console.

Comment: @muistooshort's jsfiddle works for me, on both firstName and lastName properties.

Comment: So the fiddle works as expected but your code doesn't (after removing the commas), what's different between the fiddle and your code?

Comment: I have no idea, I wish I could skype someone who can look at my screen or something and just figure it out in a few seconds, because I am pretty sure I might be doing something wrong that is just not clicking in the way this is being put out. Anyway I can link up with you mu?

Comment: Thanks just had a friend come look at it, I didn't realize I was saving the file as a second main.js file so nothing was being changed in the other file. Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your validate function as a syntax error.  You do not need to use "," after each if statement since this is a function not an object literal.

```
    validate: function(attrs) {
        if(!attrs.firstName) {
            return 'You must enter a real name.'
        }
        if(!attrs.lastName) {
            return 'You must enter a real name.'
        }
        if(attrs.email.length < 5 ) {
            return 'You must enter a real email.'
        }
        if(attrs.phone.length < 10 && attrs.phone === int) {
            return 'You must enter a real phone number, if you did please remove the dash and spaces.'
        }
        if(attrs.city.length < 2 ) {
            return 'You must enter a real city.'
        }
    },
```

Comment: I tried that, it still does not validate when I set the lastName to '', it does not throw up the error or prevent the lastName from being changed when I write it in the console in google chrome.